# iPhone sdk how to add UIButton with first and last array count in UITableView?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uibutton

I need to add a `UIButton` in my `UITableView` only with my first and last array count. I found that we can use `tableFooterView`, to add unbutton below our tableview. But how can I achieve this over my tableview and only with first and last array values? Here is my code,

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{ 

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }

    //Adding a UIButton in last row

    NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [editTable numberOfSections] - 1;
    NSLog(@"lastSectionIndex:%d",lastSectionIndex);

    // Then grab the number of rows in the last section
    NSInteger lastRowIndex = [editTable numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
    NSLog(@"lastRowIndex:%d",lastRowIndex);

    // Now just construct the index path
    NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];
    NSLog(@"last index:%@",pathToLastRow);

    if (pathToLastRow.row == lastRowIndex) 
    {
        NSLog(@"row enters");

        checkButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [checkButton1 setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 168, 168)];
        [checkButton1 addTarget:self
                         action:@selector(customActionPressed:)
               forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [checkButton1 setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Up Arrow.jpg"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        editTable.tableFooterView = checkButton1;
        [cell addSubview:checkButton1]; 
    }
```

Now I receive the buttons in every cell of my tableview. How can I give the button only to my first and last row array values? Thanks in advance.

Comment: instead of creating Button in CellforRow You can Create in ViewDidload And attach it with FooterView of table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your if condition as,

```
if ((lastSectionIndex == indexPath.section && lastRowIndex == indexPath.row ) || (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 ))
{
```

It will look like this,

```
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIButton *checkButton1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        checkButton1.tag = 100;//not recommended, I would suggest to use custom UITableViewCell class and add this button as subview inside its init method
        [checkButton1 setFrame:CGRectMake(200, 0, 168, 168)];
        [checkButton1 addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(customActionPressed:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];
        [checkButton1 setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"Up Arrow.jpg"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:0.0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [cell addSubview:checkButton1]; 
    }

   //Adding a UIButton in last row
   NSInteger lastSectionIndex = [editTable numberOfSections] - 1;
   NSLog(@"lastSectionIndex:%d",lastSectionIndex);

   // Then grab the number of rows in the last section
   NSInteger lastRowIndex = [editTable numberOfRowsInSection:lastSectionIndex] - 1;
   NSLog(@"lastRowIndex:%d",lastRowIndex);

   // Now just construct the index path
   NSIndexPath *pathToLastRow = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:lastRowIndex inSection:lastSectionIndex];
   NSLog(@"last index:%@",pathToLastRow);

   UIButton *checkButton1 = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:100];//not recommended, I would suggest to use custom UITableViewCell class and add this button as subview inside its init method
   if ((lastSectionIndex == indexPath.section && lastRowIndex == indexPath.row ) || (indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0 ))
    {
       checkButton1.hidden = NO;
    } else {
       checkButton1.hidden = YES;
    }
```

You dont have to declare `checkButton1` in .h file. Make it a local variable as shown above. Then you can set hidden property to hide/show in difference cells. Instead of doing the above, you can also create this button in custom `UITableViewCell` class and set the hidden property as `cell.checkButton1.hidden = YES`. You need to subclass `UITableViewCell` for that.

Comment: Now the button is beneath my tableview now.

Comment: @Saranya, Nice to know that. Please accept if this helped. :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of creating Button in CellforRow You can Create in ViewDidload And attach it with FooterView of table.

```
UIButton *aButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor whiteColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton setTitleColor:[UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.56] forState:UIControlStateDisabled];
    [aButton setBackgroundImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"test.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:kButtonSliceWidth topCapHeight:0] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton setTitle:@"Click me" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [aButton.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:kFontSize14]];
    [aButton setFrame:CGRectMake(10.0, 15.0, 300.0, 44.0)];
    [self.tableView setTableFooterView:aButton];
```

Same thing you can do for headerview. or else You Can Use `Viewforheader` method

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{        
    UIView *headerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 44)] autorelease]; // x,y,width,height

    UIButton *reportButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];    
    reportButton.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 0, 160.0, 40.0); // x,y,width,height
    [reportButton setTitle:@"rep" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [reportButton addTarget:self 
                     action:@selector(buttonPressed:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown];        

    [headerView addSubview:reportButton];
    return headerView;    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add first button to your table view Header And other button should be added to your footer view Secion of tableView